# The exploration of the asymptotic behavior of a simple sum. $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (k^{1/k} - 1)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, asymptotics, riemann-zeta-function, exponential-sums

An informal investigation of a sum.

Consider this sum:
$$S =\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/k} -1)$$
Does this converge? How does it behave as it diverges, if it diverges? If $k$ equaled $1$ we would get $0$ so we start at $k=2$. Very generally we can find that: $k^{1/k}$ will always be $1$ + a remainder. After subtracting $1$ from each term, each term will be a value less than $1$. Not too illuminating so far.

Let's raise the second k to a power t so we can examine how tweaking that variable affects the output $S_t = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/k^t} -1)$. When $t=1$ it is the original and the partial sums seem to rise and rise, but is unclear of the final  behavior.

Breaking $t$ out in parts, lets set $t = (1 + \frac{1}{x})$,
$$S_x=\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/k^{1+1/x}} -1).$$

Numerically, these sums seem to converge when $x$ is finite, but its difficult to calculate when x gets large. Calculating some values, we find a pattern at last! We find $S_2 = 4$ plus a remainder less than $1$. Going further $S_3 = 9$ plus a remainder less than $1$, and $S_{100} = 10,000$ plus a remainder less than $1$.
The output always seems to be the square plus a remainder! It seems true that $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/(k^{1+1/x})} -1) = \lfloor x^{2}\rfloor$$ when $x$ is the square root of any natural number greater than 1.
Here are some examples:
$S_4 = 16.238932773$,
$S_{12} = 144.5937831$,
$S_{\sqrt{1729}} = 1729.84841$,
$S_{50000} = 2500000000.988421705$.

Does that remainder ever get higher than one? Let's get another perspective on the sum to see if we can calculate that remainder at the limit as ${x \to {\infty}}$.

Time to transform the sum so we can get a handle on why its the square plus a remainder, and try to get a handle on that remainder. Remembering that $t = (1 + 1/x)$,
see that: $$k^{1/k^t}=e^{(\log k)/k^t} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \log k \right)^n}{n! k^{n t}}$$
Let's define $$S_t = \sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \log k \right)^n}{n! k^{n t}}\right) -1$$ Notice when $n=0$ we get $1$, so it cancels the $-1$ term resulting in: $$\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \log k \right)^n}{n! k^{n t}}$$
What is effectively adding column by column instead of row by row, we get:$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \log k \right)^n}{n! k^{n t}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{\left( \log k \right)^n}{k^{n t}}$$

Using the definition $$\zeta^{(n)}(t) = e^{i \pi n}\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}\frac{\log k ^{n}}{k^{t}}$$ valid for all $n\in\mathbb{R}, t\in\mathbb{C}$,

we get $$S_t = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n!}\zeta^{(n)}(nt)$$

Since we'll be looking at the Zeta function close to it's pole at $1$, let's expand $\zeta$ with the Laurent expansion of the Zeta function expanded around 1. $\gamma$ represents the Stieltjes constants.

$$\zeta(s) = \frac{1}{s-1} + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{\gamma_n}{n!}(s-1)^{n}$$
Giving us $$\zeta^{'}(s) = -\frac1{(s-1)^2} -\gamma_1 +\gamma_2(s-1)-\frac12\gamma_3(s-1)^2\cdots$$
$$\zeta^{''}(s) = \frac2{(s-1)^3} +\gamma_2 -\gamma_3(s-1)+\frac12\gamma_4(s-1)^2\cdots$$
$$\zeta^{'''}(s) = -\frac6{(s-1)^4} -\gamma_3 +\gamma_4(s-1)-\frac12\gamma_5(s-1)^2...$$
Using these interpretations and setting $s = n(1+\frac1x)$ and examining what occurs when $x \to \infty$ allows us to see why the output of $S_x$ is always $x^2$ plus a constant less than 1. As before, we can add column by column instead of row by row for the summations of the Laurent series.

Examining the largest term when $n=1$, we have $$\frac1{((1+\frac1x)-1)^2} = x^2$$ $x^2$ obviously diverges, so already we can tell the original sum $S$ diverges. Let's keep going to see how the remainder term behaves as $x \to \infty$. When $n=2$ and greater, the terms such as $\frac{2}{(s-1)^3} = \frac2{(n-1)^3}$ turn into finite values. Summing all the terms in $S_t$, setting $t=1+\frac1x$ and letting x zoom off, we arrive at the limiting behavior of the sum $S_x$.

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\Big|\Big(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/k^{1+1/x}} -1)\Big)-x^2\Big| = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{(n-1)^{n+1}} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma_n}{n!} + \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(-1)^k\frac{\gamma_n(n-k+1)^{k-2}}{(n-k+2)!(k-2)!} = C,$$

and $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\gamma_n}{n!} = \frac12 - \gamma_0,$$

and $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\Big|\Big(\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/k^{1+1/x}} -1)\Big)-x^2\Big| = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac1{(n-1)^{n+1}} + \sum_{k=3}^{\infty}\sum_{n=k}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\gamma_n(n-k+1)^{k-2}}{(n-k+2)!(k-2)!} + \frac12 - \gamma_0 = C$$ .

$\gamma_n$ is bounded by $|\gamma_n| < \frac{n!}{2^{n+1}}$, which can show convergence, and numerically it stabilizes within the realm of testing.

$$C = 0.988549601142268750644\ldots$$

So it seems $$\sum_{k=2}^\infty (k^{1/(k^{1+1/x})} -1) = x^2 + C_x,$$ where $-0.028501\ldots < C_x < C$, $x\geq1$ , and $x \in \mathbb{R}$ , where $-0.028501\ldots$ is $C_x$ when $x=1$. $C_x$ is positive when roughly $x>~1.37$.

Edit: Hi everyone, I didn't know the strict format of this site. Please see the selected answer as a beautiful solution to my first question, and please consider the rest of this post as exposition of how the sum diverges.

Comment: Please restrict to one question per post. Also, you probably meant $\sum (k^{1/k}-1)$ instead of $\sum k^{1/k}-1$.

Comment: It was phrased as if it was a lesson and this site hyper focuses on answering a question.

Comment: It is standard policy at MathOverflow to restrict to one question per post. Otherwise someone answers one of the included questions, but the proposer will not be satisfied, because the other questions are left unanswered. Multiple questions and long posts are a source of frustration. And yes, this site indeed is about answering questions.

Comment: To abide by that format, I would essentially have the first 3 lines, then answer my own question with the rest. Is it too late now? What should I do.

Comment: Well, saying "What a waste of time" is not helpful. Other than that: take it easy!

Comment: @TheHoyt What are your other questions exactly? You could summarize them at the bottom of your post for example.

Comment: I don't really have questions. I've wandered into the wrong house.

Comment: Btw, if you want the asymptotic behaviour of $\sum_{k\leq x} k^{1/k} - 1$ for $x$ large, it seems to be given by $\frac 1 2 \ln^2 x + C + \frac {\ln x} {2x} + \cdots$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The OP asks the question whether the series $S =\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(k^{1/k} -1)$ diverges.

The answer is that the series diverges, because $$k^{\frac{1}{k}}-1 = \exp\left(\frac{\ln k}{k}\right)-1>\frac{\ln k}{k} > \frac{1}{k}$$
and $\sum_{k=2}^\infty 1/k=\infty$.

Comment: Nicely done. I'm going to wait to accept this as an answer, as that first question was to merely tee off the discussion about its divergence.

Comment: In essence, the post is about the second question. My apologies.

Comment: I asked the question, the man destroyed said question. I have to give the win. However, Im new to these sites, and my intent was really to share the asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @TheHoyt -- I'm sorry your experience with MathOverFlow was not satisfactory, but it was certainly not my intent to "destroy" your question! As pointed out in the comments, the site really works best if you can formulate a precise question that can then be answered in the brief space of the answer box. It does not work well as a place to share your work, or discuss issues you have encountered. Some use a blog for that purpose.

Comment: I meant destroy as a compliment. I wasn't aware of , or understood the need why, the site operates the way it does but now I do. I hope that people will at least look at the rest of the post, to see how nicely the sum diverges.